# Mockito for Environment getExternalStorageState() android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to mockito testing, I have been trying to follow the blogs but its pretty jumbled up for now.

The motto is to test two static functions in the `FileUtility` class. The code goes below.

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String getLogFilePath(String fileName) {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        File _file;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            _file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
            if (exists(_file)) {
                return getAbsoluteFilePath(_file,fileName);
            }
        }

        _file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (exists(_file)) {
            return getAbsoluteFilePath(_file,fileName);
        }
    }

    File _file = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    if (exists(_file)) {
        return getAbsoluteFilePath(_file,fileName);
    }

    return fileName;
}

private static boolean exists(File file) {
    return file != null && file.exists();
}
```

How should i write the unit test case to test that function for inputs like "fileName=null"?

Please share some light/code into it.

Comment: You can't test static functions with mockito. Try using PowerMock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are three main paths through `getLogFilePath()`:

- If external storage is writeable and the external storage public directory is available then use it
- If external storage is writeable and the external storage public directory is not available but the external storage directory is available then use it
- In all other cases use the data directory

Writing these test cases just involves a few mocked expectations on the following methods:

- `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`
- `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`
- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
- `Environment.getDataDirectory()`

Here's an example:

```
// this test case need to mock static methods so it uses PowerMock
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// this static methods to be mocked are on Environment so that must be 'prepared'
@PrepareForTest({Environment.class})
public class StorageUtilsTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder storageDirectory = new TemporaryFolder();

    private File nonExistentDirectory;
    private File existentDirectory;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        nonExistentDirectory = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        Mockito.when(nonExistentDirectory.exists()).thenReturn(false);

        existentDirectory = storageDirectory.getRoot();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Environment.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void willUseTheExternalStoragePublicDirectoryWhenItIsAvailable() {
        // external storage is writeable
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        // the external storage public directory is available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)).thenReturn(existentDirectory);

        String fileName = "someFileName";
        String logFilePath = StorageUtils.getLogFilePath(fileName);

        Assert.assertEquals(existentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName, logFilePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void willUseTheExternalStorageDirectoryWhenItIsAvailable() {
        // external storage is writeable
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        // the external storage public directory is not available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)).thenReturn(nonExistentDirectory);
        // the external storage directory is available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).thenReturn(existentDirectory);

        String fileName = "someFileName";
        String logFilePath = StorageUtils.getLogFilePath(fileName);

        Assert.assertEquals(existentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName, logFilePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void willUseTheDataDirectoryWhenExternalStorageIsNotWriteable() {
        // external storage is not writeable
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn("not media mounted");
        // the data directory is available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getDataDirectory()).thenReturn(existentDirectory);

        String fileName = "someFileName";
        String logFilePath = StorageUtils.getLogFilePath(fileName);

        Assert.assertEquals(existentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName, logFilePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void willUseTheDataDirectoryWhenNothingElseIsAvailable() {
        // external storage is writeable
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        // but neither of the external storage directories are available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)).thenReturn(nonExistentDirectory);
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).thenReturn(nonExistentDirectory);
        // so we must fall through to the data directory
        Mockito.when(Environment.getDataDirectory()).thenReturn(existentDirectory);

        String fileName = "someFileName";
        String logFilePath = StorageUtils.getLogFilePath(fileName);

        Assert.assertEquals(existentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName, logFilePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void doesSomethingWhenGivenANullFileName() {
        // external storage is writeable
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        // the external storage public directory is available
        Mockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)).thenReturn(existentDirectory);

        String logFilePath = StorageUtils.getLogFilePath(null);

        // the assertion here will depend on what your getAbsoluteFilePath() method does with a null file name!
        Assert.assertEquals(existentDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator, logFilePath);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This uses the JUnit TemporaryFolder Rule to create (and discard on completion) a directory for the assertions. This could also be implemented using a mocked `File` instance.
- The OP did not include a definition of `getAbsoluteFilePath()` so I presumed it was something like this:

  ```
  private static String getAbsoluteFilePath(File file, String fileName) {
      return file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName;
  }
  ```
- The above example is not intended to be exhaustive, it is intended to provide *just enough* so that you can understand how it works and how to test static methods etc

Comment: I wish i could give you more stars or something rather than an upvote. The answer was very much efficient. I did some changes while testing, learnt from your explanation